# How to calculate the discriminant of a sequence of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $g(x)$ be a given polynomial with integer coefficients.

If I have a sequence of polynomials defined by $f_{n+1}(x) = ( f_n(x) + x)^2 + g(x)$, what can I say about the discriminant of $f_{n+1}$ in terms of the discriminant of $f_n$?  (The assumption is that $f_n$ also has integer coefficients.)

In particular, I am looking at the sequence generated by

$f_{0}(x) = x^2 - x$

$f_{1}(x) = (x^2 -3)^2 - x$

$f_{2}(x) = ((x^2 -3)^2 -3)^2 - x$

$f_{3}(x) = (((x^2 -3)^2 -3)^2 -3)^2 - x$

...

$f_{n+1}(x) = (f_{n}(x) + x -3)^2 - x$

What can we say about the discriminant of the sequence of polynomials?  Is there a pattern that can be proven?

Comment: 1) This question looks too general to have an explicit answer (in particular you dont say what you take as $f_0$ 2) Could you say something about the motivation for such a question ?